# Retrieve Posts By Users & Reviews On Facebook Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using the Facebook API, can I retrieve posts by users and even reviews on a Facebook fan page that I am not an admin for using Facebook API with PHP? I know I can retrieve posts the fan page has sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ONLY get the reviews of a Page with a Page Token, so you MUST be Admin of that Page. It´s written in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings#Overview

> A Page Access Token is required for all methods.

About all possibilities to read the Page feed, go check out this page in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

You can test everything easily in the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/